# Component like HorizontalList for Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, itemrenderer, horizontallist

I'm developing an Flash application in ActionScript 3.0. I need a component to render my items horizontally using an ItemRenderer. I used fl.controls.List to do this vertically and found that there's HorizontalList for Flex applications, but I can't migrate to Flex.

Is there a component that I can use or how can I create one?

Update:

I tried TileView with 1 row but it causes columns to overlap when the number of items is greater than the component's width. How can I achieve something like overflox: hidden in Actionscript 3.0?

Comment: Check layout in list Field , There is a Horizontal layout.

Comment: I'm importing my List using this directive: "import fl.controls.List;". There is no "layout" property in my List object. Am I missing something?

Comment: do you mean a TileList (locked to horizontal scrolling with a landscape aspect ratio) ?

Comment: I suppose so, but the problem with TileList is that the column width is determined by the TileList's initial width. I mean, TileList's width doesn't increase as you add items.